# Asp code for getting lat/lng from google XML

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic

I am trying to request and save in a DDBB the lat and lng from google maps xml, the code I'm using is the following :

```
            url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="&sensor=false"
            response.write "URL... : " & url &"</br>"
            Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
            objXMLDoc.setTimeouts 30000, 30000, 30000, 30000
            objXMLDoc.Open "GET", url, False
            objXMLDoc.send()

            Dim xmlLocation 
                 
            For Each xmlLocation In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("location")
                 lat = xmlLocation.selectSingleNode("lat").text   
                 lng = xmlLocation.selectSingleNode("lng").text   
                 Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(lat) & " "
                 Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(lng) & "<br>"   
            Next
```

I keep getting an error on:

```
For Each xmlLocation In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("location")
```

It says its not a method.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `objXMLDoc.responsexml` instead of `objXMLDoc` like so:

```
response.write "<hr>"

response.write objXMLDoc.responsexml.selectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").text

response.write "<hr>"

response.write objXMLDoc.responsexml.selectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").text
```